# Trigger Insert Into Separate Table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Go a quick question about triggers.

I have two tables. Namely people and attributes.

People has the following structure:

```
| id | firstname | surname | DOB | Age
```

Attributes has the following structure:

```
| id | person_id | haircolor | eyecolor | weight | height
```

And I have the following trigger:

```
 Insert Into attributes (person_id)
       SELECT id
       FROM INSERTED
```

Which when a record gets inserted in the people table, a record gets inserted into the attributes table into the person_id column where the person_id is the same id as the person table. The rest of the inserted row is empty by default.

Now when both tables are empty and I create the first record, everything goes as expected. But when I create a second record two records get inserted into the attribute table.

I need it so that when I insert one row in the people table only one corresponding row gets inserted into the attributes table.

I am using the latest version of phpmyadmin at the time of writing.

Looking forward to hearing some responses
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can do as following -

```
delimiter //
create trigger People_ins after insert on People
for each row
begin
 declare pcount int;
 select count(*) into pcount from attributes where person_id = new.id;
 if pcount = 0 then
  insert into attributes 
  (person_id) values (new.id);
 end if;
end ;//

delimiter ;
```

You can skip the condition part if its always one-to-one relation.

Comment: Thanks so much, very quick reply and was exactly what I needed.